# Reset Scala plugin after renaming a source file

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, reset

Once you rename a file, Eclipse will tell you that your objects and variables are declared twice. There was a way to reset this condition but I do not remember where exactly. It is not just `Rebuild All`.

Comment: What is your question? Which IDE?

Comment: You mean `project > clean...`? I need to clean frequently. Just now to clear a spurious error.